# Subroutine dice rolling assignment

Tags: java

I'm just learning subroutines and I'm still very, very amateurish at this. My assignment asks me to toss two dice, display what the dice display (random numbers), display total of the two die, and let the program continue until 7 or 11 is the total. We haven't done anything on arrays, so I don't know if I should use them or not.

Also, I was going to use a for loop, but how would I get the program to stop at either 7 or 11 using it? Should I try another loop?

Please help guide me on what I have to do! I'm very confused about how to make the methods and put them into the main method. Just an explanation would do!

Thank you!

Comment: Look into the documentation for java.util.Random, read about break; and return;

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have tried?

Comment: Of you haven't been taught about arrays, why would you think you need to use one?

Comment: @atk To be fair, if you haven't learned about something, you probably also haven't learned when it would be appropriate to use it.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Agreed.  My point is actually that the teacher is unlikely to assign work that requires the student to use something as basic as an array without first having taught how to use an array. I was looking to get Selma to think about the teacher's state of mind - a skill that is both very helpful in passing classes andvtests as we'll as working with people in the real world

Comment: @atk It's because I've had to use an array in another assignment before this and I didn't know how. I managed to get through it and it helped decrease my ignorance on the subject, but I'm hoping I don't have to use one here. It's an online course and so everything I'm doing, I'm pretty much learning on my own.

Comment: @Salma: Look up a tutorial online for arrays. They're incredibly simple to use and understand and are fundamentally important.

Comment: This post was automatically flagged as being "low quality". When going through them, I voted to close it since I feel that it does not show much effort on the OP's part. I know that this person is still learning, so, do you guys think I made the right decision in this case or not?

Comment: @Mike I'd give him a break (especially if the OP is really new to programming); just let him know why it was flagged as low-quality. At the very least, it looks like he put *some* effort into it.

Comment: @Salma have you read The Java Tutorial?  It's the best documentation for how Java works that I've seen. It will get you started with how to define functions and how to call them (what you seem stuck on now).  It will also help with arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the pseudocode for this problem. I won't give you the actual code but this will set you in the right direction:

```
Loop forever: {
    Integer A = Random #1-6
    Integer B = Random #1-6
    Integer total = A + B

    If total == 7 or total == 11 BREAK from the loop

    Print total

}
```

Some more hints: Looping forever is usually achieved by setting up a while loop whose condition is always true. For example, `while (true)` or `while (1 == 1)`.

Also, look into the [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class for generating a random number. It's really straightforward and it's good to start learning how to use the Java docs early in your learning process.

Comment: Should I use the Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1 provided method for the random number? Although, this provides a number from 1-10 and I need it to be from 1-6 because it's a die. Could I change the 9 to a 5?
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, in general, `Math.random() * n` will return a `double` between `0` and `n - 1`, so you could do `Math.random()*6 + 1` for a random between 1 and 6, then convert it to an integer value however you prefer.

Comment: Well, if you do it that way, it's not perfectly random; the odds of getting a 1 or 6 are half as much as the other four.

Comment: @DennisMeng What would you suggest that I use, then?

Comment: I'm used to `1 + Math.floor(6*Math.random())`. `Math.random()` doesn't quite hit 1, so `6*Math.random()` gets you everything from 0 to ~5.999999 (or just under 6), and so the floor gets you 0 to 5, with the `+ 1` getting you to 1 to 6.

Comment: Docs for [`Math.random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())

Comment: (Also, `1 + Math.floor(Random.nextInt(6))` for the equivalent using `Random`. Would actually suggest over using `Math.random()`.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a [`while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop. In your case,

```
instantiate the two dice 
while the total isn't either 7 or 11 {
    roll again
}
print out the result of the roll that wasn't either 7 or 11.
```

should be a reasonable starting point for you. I won't go into too much detail so that you still get the chance to implement the idea yourself and learn from it. If you don't know how to simulate a dice roll, @Kon's answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a subroutine that returns the total number and call it in main method in while-loop

```
class Rolling-dice {
    public static int roll() {
        // roll the first dice and display the number
        // roll the second dice and display the number
        // return total`number
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = roll();
        // while result not 7 or 11 call roll()
    }
}
```